# Java robot class

Tags: java

I have a problem with typing in Robot Class. I want the robot to type something the
user has entered. The robot for some reason can't type some of the characters. Here is my type code:

```
public void type(String s,Robot robot) {
    byte[] stringBytes = s.getBytes();

    for (byte b : stringBytes) {
        int code = b;

        if (code > 96 && code < 123)
            code = code - 32;
        robot.keyPress(code);
        robot.keyRelease(code);
    }
}
```

how can i fix this problem?

Comment: What isn't working about it, exactly?  Could you give some example input/output?

Comment: yea sure, if you input for example "http://youtube.com" it will throw exception because ":" is not recognized or something

Comment: possible duplicate of [simulate backspace key with java.awt.Robot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596641/simulate-backspace-key-with-java-awt-robot)

Comment: So add some special cases in for ones you want to support, and catch and log exceptions to that.

Comment: yes, i have taken that into account but it seems inefficent, is there no easier way?

Comment: If you want to "type back what the user entered", then surely you should be capturing a set of `KeyEvent` objects, and not a `String`...?

Comment: There is a textbox, where they enter text and i input it on the screen.

Comment: Well then, get the `KeyEvent`s sent to the text box, and then save them and replay them. There is not a key for every `String` character, far from it! (for instance you need to press 'shift' to input a colon, so that's two key presses and not one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to "type back what the user entered", then surely you should be capturing a set of `KeyEvent` objects, and not a `String`. There is not a key for every `String` character, far from it! (for instance you need to press 'shift' to input a colon, so that's two key presses and not one)

Answer (score 1):

[`Robot`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) expects key codes defined in [`KeyEvent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html).