# Can we insert Unicode Characters using Robot Class in Java?

Tags: java, swing, unicode, insert, typing

I am developing a Real time English-Sinhala Unicode translator in java.I did the translation part.But now I want to add the Final output Unicode characters to the currently active window (like a web browser).There's a way to add characters via java Robot class with
 Robot.keyPress(//keyInput) method.But is there any way to do this with java Unicode characters like u0200 hex value.If it can't be done with this way what solutions I have to resolve this.Please anyone help me ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can simulate key presses using `Robot`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596641/simulate-backspace-key-with-java-awt-robot/2596700#2596700). No, `Robot` can't see what's printed on the user's key caps. You're probably going to have to develop a [virtual keyboard](http://sourceforge.net/projects/virtualkey/). When available, Unicode glyphs make usable button labels, as shown [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons).

Addendum: Note that a [`KeyEvent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) represents a keystroke, while [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) encodes graphemes represented by glyphs. The mapping depends on the [keyboard layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout), e.g. [Sinhala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Sinhalese).

Comment: it looks like Robot can't handle arbitrary unicode. It can only handle the set of keys specified in [KeyEvent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.event.KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED). I'm trying to find a solution to this as well ... I'll answer back here if I find a way.

Comment: I appreciate your taking time to comment, but I don't understand the down-vote.

Comment: (shrugs) I cannot say why someone else down-voted the answer, but I can tell you that I'm impressed that you can cram 7 (count them, *7*) links into 6 sentences.  Woo-hoo!

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: Thanks for looking at this; your élan is always refreshing. It's a perennial problem, as the mapping relies on the host's implementation. Mine recognizes myriad layouts and a few input method variants, but Sri Lanka is not among them.