# How to simulate Keyboard press in java

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, awtrobot

I want to simulate entering a string (can contain any character) in JTextField. I am using new KeyEventData() for that. But I am not able to determine how to handle characters like {, }, ) etc and also how to append a new character to already entered characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) for this, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2596700/230513). To get `{`, for example,  you'll need to do something like this:

```
keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_OPEN_BRACKET);
keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_OPEN_BRACKET);
keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
```

Comment: so for every character i need to check its value and based on that decide whether to use shift or not.

Comment: Yes, `KeyEvent` instances are low level events.

Comment: when I use the above code for VK_PLUS, i get invalid key code exception

Comment: On my keyboard, `VK_PLUS` is unshifted, while shift-`VK_EQUALS` yields a plus sign.

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful for emulating keyevents: [How to simulate keyboard presses in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745959/how-to-simulate-keyboard-presses-in-java)

For left and right brace, KeyEvent.VK_BRACELEFT and KeyEvent.VK_BRACERIGHT
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_BRACELEFT

Hope this helps =]

Comment: @ cskoala: I am not able to determine which key to press at runtime and how to append key character to already typed string.

Comment: Sorry, what exactly are you trying to do? I thought you just wanted to simulate entering a string? Are you waiting for user input at runtime or are you putting which keys to press in your code?

Comment: I take an input from string. Then I want to simulate that value to be typed in a JTextField.

Comment: oh okay, so can't you parse the String character by character then have a switch statement with each possible character and simulate the key presses that way?

Comment: do you think that'll work for you? if so and you're confused, I can provide a small sample.

Comment: Actually I got your point, only thing I am worried is that will be a lengthy code.

Comment: Yeah, it would be pretty lengthy, but a switch statement would be the only way to differentiate which keyPress to simulate since you have to use a different KeyEvent.VK for each different character.

Answer (score 1):

check VK_BRACELEFT, VK_BRACERIGHT, VK_RIGHT_PARENTHESIS and VK_LEFT_PARENTHESIS for handling those characters.

For the appending the character, you might suppose building the list of characters or building the string.

edit: for getting the character value from the keyevent try KeyEvent.getKeyChar()