# Robot KeyEvent.VK_AT Issue in JAVA

Tags: java, swing, awt, awtrobot

I created Robot class in JAVA but there is a issue `robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_AT)` have to press `-> '@' -> at`

But it presses `'q' <-> 'Q'`

What should i do to robot press '@' symbol ?

Comment: Use VK_AT what Constant for the "@" key

Comment: VK_AT presses 'q' i guess need another constant

Comment: can you give a little more detail about what you are doing with the robot?

Comment: if you pressed `@` then it must be **`VK_AT`**

Comment: i'm using ubuntu it could be the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my keyboard, the <kbd>@</kbd> key requires combining the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>2</kbd> keys; [others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout) may vary. The test image below was produced by adding the following to this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2596700/230513).

Addendum: As noted in comments by @neat159, the host OS keyboard control panel setting must match the *intended* keyboard layout being tested.

```
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_2);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_2);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
```

[image]

Comment: i'm using ubuntu 13v how can i do with ubuntu ?

Comment: my combination is [Alt Gr] + [Q] = '@' but i get errorException in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key code
 at sun.awt.windows.WRobotPeer.keyPress(Native Method)
 at java.awt.Robot.keyPress(Unknown Source)
 at RobotTest$1.mouseReleased(RobotTest.java:37)
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 12, IcedTea6.

Comment: It's really interesting it drives me crazy i'm working on it almoust 5 hours.
Now I Tried on WINDOWS 7 Getting Same Issue also combination is [Alt Gr] + [Q] = '@'
What is the problem i dont get it?

My Code is:

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT_GRAPH);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT_GRAPH);

I'm getting Error:
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key code
 at sun.awt.windows.WRobotPeer.keyPress(Native Method)
 at java.awt.Robot.keyPress(Unknown Source)

Comment: You may have to change something in the host OS's keyboard control panel; mine's set to U.S. for both Mac OS X and Ubuntu. Interestingly, mine accepts a `VK_ALT` modifier, but silently ignores `VK_ALT_GRAPH`.

Comment: yes you were right my keybouard language was turkish so the problem is language i changed it to english problem solved thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the constant KeyEvent.VK_AMPERSAND ?